# Is it possible to redirect users to OTP function before accessing password reset form in Django views.py?

Tags: django

Suppose I have 2 Functions in my views.py

I just want user's first attempt first the function (OTP function) and then go to the second form ( password change form )

even after they type URL for PassChangeForm in browser url , they directly redirect to OTP function

Suppose I have 2 Functions in my views.py

the first function is to enter OTP and the second function is to get the password reset form

I want user to first attempt OTP enter the form and then after go for the password reset form

```
path('PassChangeForm/',views.PassChangeForm, name="PassChangeForm" ),
```

Even they PassChangeForm type in Browser url they get automatically redirected on OTP form